# Where can I find the Telekinesis Spell?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Where can I pick up a Telekinesis Spell Book in Skyrim?
I haven't looked too thoroughly, and am just now interested after watching an episode of "*Things To Do In ..*".

Answer (score 6):

Here's a list of where you can get it:

- Purchase from Tolfdir at the College of Winterhold.
- Purchase from Wylandriah at Mistveil Keep.
- Found in Labyrinthian during The Staff of Magnus quest. (Note by me: Right when you enter the area, to the right on a table)
- Found at Shearpoint.

Taken from [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Telekinesis_%28Skyrim%29)

Comment: Much obliged man, thank you :) im gonna have fun with this haha

Comment: @AllenMcGee, do note that vendors will only stock spell books when your skill in that category of magic is high enough - Telekenesis appears to be Adept level, so you'll need 50 in Alteration before you can find it for sale.

Comment: There's one in Riften, inside the mead place, bottom floor, look behind the counter under the shelf.